# Using python, elementtree, xml parser to get attributes not working for some reason?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm new to python and parsing xml, but I'm having trouble with a particular xml file which is spat out by a program I work with.  I'm trying parse this xml file using python and elementtree in order to extract the url data (the URL below is fake).  Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

my python code:

```
def xmlTreeParser(fileName,attribute,tagName):
tree = ET.parse(fileName)
root = tree.getroot()

attribArray = [element.attrib[attribute] for element in root.findall(tagName)]
print attribArray

xmlTreeParser("xml_file.xml",'text','Expr')
```

here's my xml file:

```
<Query id="f9cef041-085d-47e0-8d16-15e36bba1ec8" name="">
  <Description />
  <JustSortedColumns />
  <Conditions linking="All">
    <Condition class="PDCT" enabled="True" readOnly="False" linking="Any">
      <Condition class="SMPL" enabled="True" readOnly="False">
        <Operator id="Contains" />
        <Expressions>
          <Expr class="ENTATTR" id="Person.LinkedInUrl" />
          <Expr class="CONST" type="String" kind="Scalar" value="https://www.linkedin.com/Bill-Smith" text="https://www.linkedin.com/Bill-Smith" />
        </Expressions>
      </Condition>
    </Condition>
  </Conditions>
</Query>
```

The python I wrote works just fine on another, test, xml file that I wrote myself.  I'm at a loss as to why I can't parse this particular block of xml.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Look into `xpath` - `findall` isn't recursive. There are only three children of root, none of them have an attribute `text`, so you don't get anything else. `xpath` will let you look for things farther down in the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific call you make, you need to add this syntax to reach the tag `Expr` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example)):

```
xmlTreeParser("xml_file.xml",'text','.//Expr')
```

But also your Xml doesn't have all attributes like text, you should prevent errors like this :

```
attribArray = [element.attrib.get(attribute, '') for element in root.findall(tagName)]
# -----------------------------^
print(attribArray)

xmlTreeParser("xml_file.xml",'text','.//Expr')
```

Comment: Sorry I went MIA--I finally have time to look at this again.  Thanks a lot for the specific answer.  However, I seem to be getting an error:  `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it--simple syntax error.  Thanks again!